# new activity vs 2 x setContentView in the same activity

Tags: java, android

I'm designing navigation app using Osmdroid and OSRM. I have MainActivity which shows map and is beeing used for navigation purposes to display current location, route, speed etc.
Now i want to add functionality to set home address and work address but i want to do it in new View since it would be struggle to hide all of the buttons, stop follow direction and creating new View seems like better apporach.

1. First idea is to create new activity set new contentview and play there BUT to do that i would need to inform activity on start that now i will be setting for example home address not work address. If it was a function i would just pass int variable to function and inside of it make if statements - 1 is work, 2 is home etc.
2. Second idea is to just make a function in the same activity to set new content view, make return as location, and then save result to address i want it to be set. Although if after this operation i will call old contentview i want be back to the previous state of the old content (for example there was a route already set)

Is there better way to do it ?

Comment: 1. You can pass data between Activities via Intent. 2. You can use multiple fragments & use the Single Activity architecture as well.

Comment: So as far as i understand intent is kinda like a variable that is beeing passed into function ? Meaning - if i will start activity and pass intent to it and later finish activity (finish() ) and then start activity again without passing value in intent, the previous passed intent wont be available anymore ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with  startActivityForResult:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetKnownPlaces.class);
    intent.putExtra("lat", geoLastLocation.getLatitude());
    intent.putExtra("lon", geoLastLocation.getLongitude());
    intent.putExtra("title", getString(R.string.KnownPlaces_title_home));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

     @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            navi.homeAddress.setCoords(data.getDoubleExtra("lat", 0), data.getDoubleExtra("lon", 0));
        }
        if (requestCode == 2) {
            navi.workAddress.setCoords(data.getDoubleExtra("lat", 0), data.getDoubleExtra("lon", 0));
        }

        if (requestCode == 3) {
            navi.favAddress.setCoords(data.getDoubleExtra("lat", 0), data.getDoubleExtra("lon", 0));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("home ", "onActivityResult: " + navi.homeAddress.getLatitude());
    Log.d("home ", "onActivityResult: " + navi.workAddress.getLatitude());

}
```

Then in 2nd Activity:

```
    title.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("title"));
    map.init();

    GeoPoint lastLocation = new GeoPoint(getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lat",0), 
    getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lon",0));
```